# Typescript/Angular type argument is not accepted by WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a generic helper test function (which will be extended later) ...

```
 public static createComponent<T>(component : Type<T>) : ComponentFixture<T>{

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;

    TestBed.compileComponents();

    fixture  = TestBed.createComponent(component);

    return fixture;
  }
```

When I try and invoke this function ....

```
myFixture  = MyHelper.createComponent(MyComponent);
```

I get a little red squiggly line on MyComponent which says ...

`argument of type MyComponent is not assignable to parameter type Type<MyComponent>`

However the code works and the component compiles properly. Any ideas what this error means?

Comment: I don't get the errors.